Select by value in list in mySQL
I've got an older table where some IDs are stored in a varchar as comma separated list.
name street  some_ids
Pete Teststr 3,4,7,2
Tom  Teststr 1,4,7,3
Inga Teststr 3,7,2,5

I.e. need to find the entries containing 2 in column "some_ids" I tried:
WHERE 2 IN (some_ids) = 0 results
WHERE 3 IN (some_ids) = only rows where some_ids starts with 3 = 2 results
Another possibility is to use find_in_set() but there are lots of rows in the table and I want to use the index which isn't by find_in_set().
Any ideas?

to use an index you are going to have to fix your schema to have a new table with one id per row (and the id or whatever indicating which row in your current table it applies to).  if you aren't doing that, you should just use find_in_set.

try regexp, but Islam's answer is easiest if you can change the text to be pre and postfixed with commas.

Does this answer your question? Running a select on a list of comma separated values in PHP

@gbjbaanb  regexp/like will work, but find_in_set is designed for this exact thing so should be preferred

Thanks guys, you helped me a lot and I will go temporarily with find_in_set() and change the table design to a reference table storing each ID relation in an own row.
The multi-valued solution is a great approach...never seen such.

Here's a solution to make a multi-valued array on the comma-separated string, after forming it into JSON array syntax. The EXPLAIN shows that the query will use the index, if we search the exact same expression.
mysql> create table mytable (name text, street text, some_ids text);

mysql> insert into mytable values ('Pete', 'Teststr', '3,4,7,2');

mysql> alter table mytable add key ((cast(concat('[',some_ids,']') as unsigned array)));

mysql> explain select * from mytable where 3 member of (concat('[',some_ids,']'));
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | functional_index | functional_index | 9       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+

The multi-valued index feature requires MySQL 8.0.17 or later. If you're still using MySQL 5.x, and you want to optimize a search with an index, then you must normalize your table, and not store comma-separated lists.

I think you could try to search with LIKE, and to simplify the searching you can add first , at the begining and end of the some_ids column.
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CONCAT(',', some_ids, ',') LIKE '%,2,%'

